# get page access token when having application access token in facebook, using php

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Do you have any idea on how I can get the page access token when I have the application access token of and application that has autorizations to access all data of the user who owns that page?

(I'm using php)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, you need a user access token to access `/me/acccounts`.

Comment: That means that if I have an application that has access to a page, I can't write code to post a message in that page if I'm not logged-in to facebook?

Comment: @simoha you can, you just need a page or user token instead. An App access token will not work for pages

Comment: But the problem is that page token expires (application access token doesn't), my script will be running on server without human interaction... (For information I can do a post to a user profile page using application access token, but when I try to post to a facebook page that belongs to that user I can't...)

Comment: @simoha the page access token only invalidates based on conditions of the user, it doesn't expire. Also an App Access Token *can only be used* for posting to a user profile.  It is not supported for pages and there is no workaround for it.